# Flask throwing AttributeError upon being unable to find variable, despite it being there

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6

I've got a wee-bit of an issue, Flask seems to think that there is no attribute `bp` in these blueprint classes, and it adds the blueprint routes and yet still logs an error, it's driving me up the wall.

**app.py import code**

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('blueprint'):

    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename).split(os.sep)
            module = ".".join(fullpath)[:-3]

            try:
                module = importlib.import_module(module)
                prefix = module.__name__.split('.')[-1:][0]
                if prefix.startswith('_'):
                    app.register_blueprint(module.bp)
                else:
                    app.register_blueprint(
                        module.bp, url_prefix=f'/{prefix}')
            except Exception as error:
                print(f"{type(error)} Unable to load {module}: {error}")
```

**example blueprint (i.e index.py)**

```
bp = Blueprint('', __name__)

@bp.route('/')
def index(*args, **kw):

    return render_template('index.html')
```

**output**

```
<class 'AttributeError'> Unable to load <module 'blueprint._index' from '~~~/blueprint/_index.py'>: module 'blueprint._index' has no attribute 'bp'
```

As you can see the `bp` variable is there, and the routes are added, but without a `try/except` the routes aren't added.. its rather annoying, and i'd rather not just `pass` them..

**edit**

**directory tree**

```
  - app.py
  - blueprints/
      - index.py
      - etc.py
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the directory tree for the application?

Comment: Try renaming your `index.py` file to `__init__.py`

Comment: i've done so @OluwafemiSule

Comment: Oh wait, that worked, thank you @AArias